# substr(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated ? Why PHP 8.1

Tags: php, php-8, php-8.1

I have this Code PHP in my Files

```
function getH1()
{
    $h1 = callDescriptor('h1');
    return ucfirst(substr($h1, 0, 56));
}
```

After Upgrade to PHP 8.1 i got this Error Messages:

```
Deprecated
    
substr(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated
```

Does someone have an Idee ?

Downgrade to PHP 8.0 takes the same Effekt

Comment: Replace with empty string if null `$h1 = callDescriptor('h1') ?? '';`

Answer (score 1):

The value of $h1 is `null` in some case which is not allowed to be passed inside of `substr` method. Check the value before processing it.

```
$h1 = callDescriptor('h1');
if ($h1 !== null) {
  return ucfirst(substr($h1, 0, 56));
}

//otherwise return something else
```